# firefox remote debugging using websocket

Tags: javascript, c++, json, google-chrome, firefox

I can debug chrome remotely by passing --remote-debugging-port=9222 then I send request using curl : curl localhost:9222/json to get the ids and debugging urls of pages then I use the urls to control chrome with websockets in c++ by sending and receiving json packets which like selenium but better and don't need chromedriver or selenium driver , I also did the same by html5 websockets and controled chrome through it

in firefox I can't debug the browser through another browser or websockets 
is there a way to do this thing with firefox